# Lendo 2 vezes um array

Tags: php

Bom tenho o seguinte array:

```
$teste = array(1,2,3,4);
```

Quando quero escrever ele na tela eu faço assim?

```
foreach ($teste as $c) {

    echo $c;

}
```

O resultado é: 1234

Preciso escrever o resultado 2 vezes e seguindo a ordem, assim: 11223344

Alguém sabe como fazer isso usando apenas um `foreach`?

OBS: O código que está dentro do `foreach` e grande e não quero que repetir ele, quero achar alguma maneira de fazer isso no `foreach`

Comment: Não basta fazer `echo $c, $c`? https://repl.it/@acwoss/EvenOutstandingRuby

Comment: Não da, esse foi um exemplo resumido, o código e grande e não quero ter que repetir ele, tenho que fazer isso no `foreach`

Comment: Então seu exemplo não reproduz o problema real, deixando sua pergunta insuficientemente clara. Por favor, edite a pergunta elaborando um [mcve].

Comment: Acabei de editar ela

Comment: não pode ter um _loop_ dentro do `foreach`? tipo `while ($contador < 2)`??

Comment: Sim, boa ideia.

Comment: Existe, também, sempre a possibilidade de você refatorar seu código e colocar aquilo que é reutilizável em funções.

Comment: Tem como fornecer o `foreach` e o respetivo código lá dentro no pastebin ?  Para que o pessoal possa ter uma ideia do que está a falar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu recomendaria você refatorar o seu código. Se ele é reutilizável, poderia muito bem estar definido em uma função. Nesse caso, bastaria fazer:

```
foreach ($teste as $c) {
    echo foo($c), foo($c);
}
```

Mas se quiser contornar isso, você pode percorrer o *array* através de um gerador:

```
function doubleForeach($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $item) {
        yield $item;
        yield $item;
    }
}
```

Assim, basta você fazer:

```
$teste = array(1,2,3,4);
$iterator = doubleForeach($teste);

foreach ($iterator as $c) {
    echo $c;
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/NeedyVirtualCodeview)</sup>

Comment: Muito bom sua solução

Answer (score 1):

Como alternativa, podes controlar usando outra estrutura de repetição

```
foreach ($teste as $c) {
  for (int $i=0; $i<2; $i++){
    echo $c;
  }
}
```